# How can I fix a broken SMB share of a printer with Windows 10

Tags: windows, samba, printing

I have a printer connected and configured to my Raspberry Pi. It is installed through CUPS and shared through SMB. For about half a year this worked flawless in printing from my Windows 10 laptop. All of a sudden it stopped working without a change in configuration of SMB or Windows 10, except for regular updates. Printing from the Raspberry as well as printing through the CUPS share through AirPrint still works.

I tried reconnecting the printer on the Windows machine, but all it says it can see the printer, but cannot connect to it. Therefore I checked the logs and can find:

```
[2021/11/07 21:23:53.799872,  5] 
  ../source3/auth/auth_ntlmssp.c:196(auth3_check_password)
  Checking NTLMSSP password for **MACHINE**\**USER** failed: NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER, authoritative=1
[2021/11/07 21:23:53.799975,  3] ../source3/auth/auth_util.c:2226(do_map_to_guest_server_info)
  No such user **USER** [**MACHINE**] - using guest account
[2021/11/07 21:23:53.800208,  5] ../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_server.c:1011(ntlmssp_server_postauth)
  server session key is invalid (len == 0), cannot do KEY_EXCH!
[2021/11/07 21:23:53.800325,  0] ../auth/gensec/gensec.c:305(gensec_verify_features)
  Did not manage to negotiate mandatory feature SIGN
[2021/11/07 21:23:53.800478,  4] ../source3/smbd/sec_ctx.c:438(pop_sec_ctx)
  pop_sec_ctx (65534, 65534) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
[2021/11/07 21:23:53.800579,  2] ../source3/rpc_server/srv_pipe.c:1099(api_pipe_bind_auth3)
  Auth failed (NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)
[2021/11/07 21:23:53.800682,  3] ../source3/rpc_server/srv_pipe.c:1881(process_complete_pdu)
  DCE/RPC fault sent!Disconnect after fault
```

So it seems after reverting to the guest user, which is correct according to my config

```
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = yes
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
```

the key exchange is failing and hence the access is denied.

1. What has changed, that the access is not granted anymore?
2. Which configuration do I have to change to fix this issue and use the printer through the SMB share again?

Comment: sounds like a windows update broke it ... please explore a fix in windows

Comment: @jsotola it seems you are right, I just found https://www.tomshardware.com/news/printnightmare-fix-breaks-network-printing as a possible explanation

Comment: And as of today my Samba share works again withoutnchanging anything in the configuration.